# Read comma-separated sequence from DataFrame to string in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame *df* which has a column [Main] and looks like this:

```
[Main]
Label1_Dim=    
Label1_Formula= PP    
Label2_Name= Customer 
Label2_Value= Tech Service, INC    
Label2_Dim=
```

I want to store the line 
`Label2_Value= Tech Service, INC` in a string, more precisely just the
`Tech Service, INC` part.

```
pos_customer=df[df['[Main]'] == 'Label2_Name= Customer']
pos_customer_index = pos_customer.index
customer = df.iloc[pos_customer.index[0]+1]['[Main]']

customer=customer[13:]
```

My Code finds the previous line, stores the next line in a string and strips the first 13 characters which should result in `customer = "Tech Service, INC"`

But there seems to be a problem with the **comma**. Usually this code works for me, but in a line with a comma it just skips it and goes to `Label2_DIM=` instead. I don´t know why and i also tried python split()-method but i didn´t solve it.

I hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: What is expected output ? also would be great if you paste the DataFarme  .

Comment: Do you want only the strings after "=" in the  `Main` column?

Comment: Please, edit your post and add the desired output example. 
The first example of a df does not look like a DataFrame actually.

Comment: I think the problem could be how you read the DataFrame in from file so might be worth posting that too.

Comment: i want to have the string after the "=" in the line `Label2_Value= Tech Service, INC ` yes. If i deleted the `,INC` manually it works fine and i get `customer= Tech Service` but i want to have also the other part in my string.

Comment: @MattisSeehaus,  See the answer below, i Just tried to simulate your  sample example to show to get the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood your question then below should work for you.

Example DataFrame:

```
>>> df
                              Main
0            Label2_Name= Customer
1  Label2_Value= Tech Service, INC
```

assuming you want the strings after `=` only  then try `replace` method using `regex` as follows:

```
>>> df.Main.replace(r'.*=', '', regex=True)
0              Customer
1     Tech Service, INC
Name: Main, dtype: object
```

If you want to that particular(`Label2_Value= Tech Service, INC`) line replaced then:

```
>>> df.Main.replace(r'^Label2_Value=', '', regex=True)
0    Label2_Name= Customer
1    Tech Service, INC      <--- here it is
Name: Main, dtype: object
```

**Without regex Just with `replace`:**

```
>>> df.Main.replace('Label2_Value= Tech Service, INC', 'Tech Service, INC')
0    Label2_Name= Customer
1        Tech Service, INC
Name: Main, dtype: object
```